# How to trigger Oauth2 logout in Spring?

Tags: spring, logout, oauth-2.0

When I delete currently logged in user (itself) who can I trigger /oauth/logout from Java code?

This service method is called from REST controller:

```
public ServiceResponse<?> deleteYourself(Principal principal) {
        ServiceResponse<?> serviceResponse = new ServiceResponse<>(ResponseStatus.SYSTEM_UNAVAILABLE);

        try {
            String username = principal.getName();
            User user = userPersistenceService.getByUsername(username);

            if (user != null) {
                userPersistenceService.delete(user.getId());
                serviceResponse.setStatus(ResponseStatus.SUCCESS);
                //TODO: trigger logout HERE

            } else {
                serviceResponse.setStatus(ResponseStatus.ACCOUNT_NOT_FOUND);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            serviceResponse.setStatus(ResponseStatus.SYSTEM_INTERNAL_ERROR);
        }
        return serviceResponse;
    }
```

The things is that, even though I deleted my account from DB, it is still available in Spring memory and I can use same token to access resources.

Comment: Here is my 2cents. I have used cookie based approach for determining the session. During logout, I just clear the cookie and effectively prompts login during the next invocation

Comment: Thanks, but I want Spring Server to handle it internally.